# Extraer fecha como String Sqlserver C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, json, string

Cuando ejecuto una consulta en *sql server* desde *C#* los campos del tipo fecha se extraen como `Date(1445580000000)` al formatearlo en JSON. Aunque en la consulta especifique el *CONVERT* para que lo haga en `yyyy-mm-dd`, me sucedió lo mismo alguna vez en *php* y en la conexión se especificaba algo como `GetDateAsString=>true` para resolverlo.

Es posible definir eso en la conexión o en el *sqlCommand* o *DataReader*, o debo recorrer los datos para convertir la fecha manualmente, y luego volver a recorrerla para convertirlo en *JSON*. Lo que me consumirá más recursos, ya que son más de 10 mil *rows*. ¿Alguna idea?.

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CIS"].ConnectionString);
            string select = "EXECUTE dbo.getInforme";
            sqlConnection.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(select, sqlConnection);
            da.Fill(dt);

 System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            Dictionary<string, object> row;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                }
                rows.Add(row);
            }

            sqlConnection.Close();
            serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
            Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(rows));
```

Nota: dbo.getInforme es un procedimiento almacenado que devuelve esta información
[image: Datos de la consulta]

Comment: ¿Puedes incluir en tu pregunta el contenido de `dbo.getInforme` por favor? ([Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenos días, hace un tiempo me había surgido un problema parecido, con fechas, tal vez esta función pueda servirte

```
DateTime.FromOADate(double);
DateTime.FromBinary(long);
DateTime.FromFileTime(long);
DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(long);
```

Cada uno de los métodos anteriores devuelve un objeto `DateTime`, tomando parámetro formatos de fechas numéricos, como el número que diste de ejemplo.

Después sí gustas desde la base de datos puedes dar el formato de fecha que desees, con el siguiente código devuelves la fecha en un dormato dd/mm/aaaa

`SELECT CAST(Convert(VARCHAR(10), Fecha, 103) AS VARCHAR(10)) FROM  [tuTabla]`.
Hacer una doble conversión, para que salga como un tipo string, y su integridad no se vea afectada.

Otra cosa que puede estar afectando es el código de fecha que usas, puedes usar el ISO(112) que devuelve aaammdd, ODBC canónico(120) aaaa-mm-dd, el Japonés(111) aa/mm/dd

Comment: Perfecto, el CAST me funciona muy bien, Gracias

Comment: ¿Te funcionó la solución?

Comment: Si asi es, Tenia Casteado otros campos, pero no se me ocurrió con la fecha, ya que En php Siempre las había extraído como string.

Comment: Me alegro en poder ayudarte